# How can i do "source in" using shell script to set environment variable

Tags: linux, shell

To set environment variable, i am doing source in (by using the below command) whenever i start to work in my Linux Working environment
`. /opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52`

When add the this line(`". /opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52"`) in to my shell script

Its not running, it returns some error.
I created alias also. even though not able to execute this.

```
alias test='. /opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52'
test
```

So how can i do "source in" with in script instead of giving this command manually

Comment: If you put double quotes around it as shown in your example that will give you a syntax error.  Remove the double quotes.

Comment: For highliting purpose, i am don double quotes....

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. In BASH you can do both:

```
. /path/to/your/skript
```

or

```
source /path/to/your/skript
```

What ist your path to the script you want to source? Is it '/opt/fedex/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52'

then you should do this:

```
   . '/opt/fedex/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52'
```

or

```
  source '/opt/fedex/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52'
```

Comment: source '/opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52'

or 

. '/opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52' 

$ sh s5.sh
s5.sh: line 1: /opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52: No such file or directory

Comment: Is your path actually '/opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52'? This is something only you can really verfy.

Comment: $ source /opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env rev.52

            Environment phase (default=prod): devel

                          User build project: rev
                          User build release: 52.0
                            User build label: devel
                                User OrgName: srs
                        User OrgName release: 52.0
                                User AppName: rev
                        User AppName release: 52.0


Reading rev.env ... done.

Comment: Are you sourcing two files? One with an absolute path '/opt/fedex/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env' and one with a relative path 'rev.52'?

Comment: The above command working fine. But when i add the same line in my shell script, its return error

Comment: @ASHOK: What do you use for your interactive shell and which shell do you use for you scripts? Is it the same shell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `source` command. That is:

```
source /path/to/file
```

And note, if you mention "some error", we can't help much with that. Unless you are specifying what kind of errors were those.

Comment: But when i do using script, go the below error............$ sh s5.sh
/opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env: line 125: print: command not found
            Environment phase (default=prod): /opt/kmc/pbs/env/1.1/etc/setup.env: line 70: print: command not found